# Storing Percentages in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to store a percentage value in a MySQL database but when ever I try and set the value of the percentage column to 100%, I get an "Out of range value" error message.

I am currently using a DECIMAL(5,2) type and I need to be able to store values from 0% up to 100% (with 2dp when the value isn't an integer) ( the values are being calculated in a php script).

All values are fine apart from 100% which triggers the error.

Am I misunderstanding something or is there something else I am missing?

EDIT:  The table was created using the following sql

```
CREATE TABLE overviewtemplate
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(32),
numberOfTests INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Please add a Description",
percentageComplete DECIMAL(5,2),
numberPassed INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
numberFailed INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

EDIT 2:  This is the code of the SQL query

```
$numberOfPasses = 5;
$numberOfFails = 5;
$percentageComplete = 100.00;

$sqlquery = "UPDATE `overviewtemplate` 
             SET numberPassed = {$numberOfPasses}, 
                 numberFailed = {$numberOfFails}, 
                 percentageComplete = {$percentageComplete}
             WHERE description = '{$description}'";
```

EDIT 3:  FIXED - Had a syntax error in my table names which meant it was trying to update a wrong table.

Comment: are you sure the value you are inserting is below or equal to hundred? have you printed the value before saving it just to check?

Comment: Yes I've printed it out and it prints 100.  I've also tried hard coding the value 100 into the sql query and it still gives me the error.

Comment: please go to mysql...write a query.. show create table TABLEName, and paste the schema here..I will like to see it..thanks.

Comment: I added the SQL I used to create the table is that what you meant?

Comment: What happens if you change the declaration to `DECIMAL(6, 2)`?  Also, can you show the code that causes the error by inserting the value?

Comment: @unknownSPY it works all okay on my end..I just created the table..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Even changing the feild type to DECIMAL(6,2) has no effect. (I have also added the query code to the question)

Comment: Ah I fixed it.  Had an error elsewhere in my php syntax. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

With your declaration you should be able to save even 999.99 without trouble. Check if you have set any rule for it not be bigger than 100? If yes then set it to be less than or equal to 100.00

It could be in a trigger.

Comment: Thats what I thought (and I have tried 100.00).  Everything over 99.99 gives me the error.

Comment: Check if you have trigger for the table and share the code.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what a trigger is. Also, which code are you referring to?

Comment: Another way to set limit is in sql you could have set the limit... using check(0,100] what is the sql of you table

Comment: `ALTER TABLE overviewtemplate ADD percentageComplete DECIMAL(5,2);`

Comment: try ALTER TABLE overviewtemplate ADD percentageComplete DECIMAL(5,2) check(0,100.01);

Comment: Is your check syntax correct?  Because I am getting a syntax error in the check statement

Comment: Sorry I was away in a meeting. In that code I added check condition to code shared by you. try this way. Drop the table after saving the data. Recreate the table and there for the percentagecomplete column modify your code to     percentageComplete decimal(5,2) check(0,100.01)